# Stepper Motor Inconsistent Jittering

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield, stepper-motor

I am trying to run a stepper motor using an Arduino stepper motor shield like the [Adafruit V1 motor shield](https://www.adafruit.com/product/81). In my code I am just trying to get the motor to rotate forwards and backwards. When I first try uploading and running the code I can get a forward and reverse rotation, but then the motor begins jittering inconsistently. I have tried changing my wiring setup but generally get the same results. [Here is the data sheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf/1310364/Handson/17HS4401S/1) for the motor I am using. I have the board it connected to a 12v battery. I also got the same problem when trying to drive the motor using just an H-drive chip. I have included my code below as well as a picture of my wiring. [Here is a video of the jitter](https://youtu.be/L0Yi0MTBdww).

```
#include <AFMotor.h>
AF_Stepper motor(200, 1);
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);           // set up Serial library at 9600 bps
Serial.println("Stepper test!");

motor.setSpeed(120);  // 10 rpm   

motor.step(100, FORWARD, SINGLE); 
motor.release();
delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
motor.step(200, FORWARD, DOUBLE);

delay(1000);
motor.step(200, BACKWARD, DOUBLE);
delay(1000);
}
```

[image]

Comment: please run the example code that is included with the library